# Efficient way to sort Matrix elements into separate bins in Python

Tags: python

I'm sorting matrix elements into separate bins.

The approach is: If the difference of each element and the 1st element in existing list is smallest, then add it to the current list. If not, create a new list and add the element there.

Following is my code which I'm applying on a small `3X3` test matrix of random numbers, as is evident, I'm using multiple `for` loops and and `if` staements to achieve this and hence it isn't memory efficient and is consuming a lot of time to execute. Is there a better way to handle this in python? Please recommend.

```
import numpy as np 
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

A = np.random.random((3, 3))

#Initialize the first cluster
k1 = [A[0,0]]
#Initialize the set of clusters
K = [k1]
#Threshold value
Theta = 0.3

counter = 1

for i in range(A.shape[1]):
    for j in range(A.shape[0]):
        diff = []
        for l in K:
            diff_l = abs(A[i,j] - l[0])
            diff.append(diff_l)
            mini = min(float(s) for s in diff)
            x = diff.index(min(diff))
            if mini < Theta:
                K[x].append(A[i,j])
            else:
                counter = counter+1
                new_list = 'k'+str(counter)
                new_list= []
                new_list.append(A[i,j])
                K.append(new_list)

print len(K)
```

Comment: It would very beneficial if you could show how you are doing it now.

Comment: Sure, following is the code. I'm currently applying this on a text matrix of random numbers I created.

Comment: A = np.random.random((3, 3))

#Initialize the first cluster
k1 = [A[0,0]]
#Initialize the set of clusters
K = [k1]
#Threshold value
Theta = 0.3

counter = 1

for i in range(A.shape[1]):
 for j in range(A.shape[0]):
  diff = []
  for l in K:
   diff_l = abs(A[i,j] - l[0])
   diff.append(diff_l)
   mini = min(float(s) for s in diff)
   x = diff.index(min(diff))
   if mini < Theta:
    K[x].append(A[i,j])
   else:
    counter = counter+1
    new_list = 'k'+str(counter)
    new_list= []
    new_list.append(A[i,j])
    K.append(new_list)

Comment: It is best to edit this into the question.  Python especially suffers from lack of indenting.  If you highlight the code and the press the `{}` button at the top of the editor it will save the formatting by indenting by 4 spaces.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I have edited the question as per your recommendation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some alternative clustering (binning) methods.

I assumed that the line `mini = min(float(s) for s in diff)` and the following code was indented incorrectly. If the indent was correct then that is your problem.  If not, here are three implementations that might speed up the work:

#### Method #1:

Here is an implementation of the original code with redundancies removed and a comprehension for the inner loop:

```
def method1():
    K = [[A[0, 0]]]
    for element in A.flatten():
        min_diff = min((abs(element - l[0]), i) for i, l in enumerate(K))
        if min_diff[0] < Theta:
            K[min_diff[1]].append(element)
        else:
            K.append([element])
```

#### Method #2:

This is bit more complex, in that it keeps a sorted list of the first elements, and for each element first does an efficient lookup to find the two closest first elements, and then performs the distance/Theta calc against only the two closest.

```
import bisect
def method2():
    global A
    A = np.random.random(A.shape)
    data_iter = iter(A.flatten())
    K = [[next(data_iter)]]
    first_elements = [K[0][0]]
    for element in data_iter:
        x = bisect.bisect_left(first_elements, element)
        if x == 0:
            # below lowest value
            min_diff = abs(element - first_elements[0]), x
        elif x == len(first_elements):
            # above highest value
            min_diff = abs(element - first_elements[-1]), x-1
        else:
            min_diff = min((abs(element - l[0]), i)
                           for i, l in enumerate(K[x-1:x+1]))
        if min_diff[0] < Theta:
            K[min_diff[1]].append(element)
        else:
            first_elements.insert(x, element)
            K.insert(x, [element])
```

#### Method #3:

I was not quite sure why you are using the first element found outside of the range of theta to define the grouping center, so I tried a small experiment.  This sorts the data, and then builds clusters that are built around 90% of theta above the minimum value in each cluster.  So the results will not match the other methods, but it is quite a bit faster.

```
def method3():
    global A
    A = np.random.random(A.shape)
    K = []
    target = -1E39
    for element in np.sort(A.flatten()):
        if element - target > Theta:
            target = element + Theta * 0.9
            K.append([])
        K[-1].append(element)
```

#### Timing Test Code:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.random((100, 100))

# Threshold value
Theta = 0.03

from timeit import timeit

def runit(stmt):
    print("%s: %.3f" % (
        stmt, timeit(stmt + '()', number=10,
                     setup='from __main__ import ' + stmt)))

runit('method0')
runit('method1')
runit('method2')
runit('method3')
```

#### Run Times

4 Methods:

```
0. Original
1. Original recast to more Pythonic
2. Use a search to minimize the number of comparisons
3. Sort the values, and then cluster
```

For the run times, I had to decrease Theta.  With the original theta there are only very small number of clusters with the data given.  If the number of clusters is small method #2 is not a lot faster.  But as the number of clusters goes up method #2 will get much faster than methods #0 and #1.  Method #3 (the sort) is fastest by far.

```
method0: 5.641
method1: 4.430
method2: 0.836
method3: 0.057
```

(Seconds, small numbers are better)

Comment: Thank you very much Stephen, really appreciate your time. Method 1 significantly improved the response time. Will try method 2 and 3.